# Select the n'th html DOM element with the same ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The project I'm working has a code where there are several sub components getting loaded into the main view and some of them actually have same ID's.

The code part is like below after loading,

```
<div id="container">
    <div></div>
    ...
    <div id="subject"></div>
    ..
    <div id="some_other"></div>
    ...
    <div id="subject"></div>
    ...
</div>
<div id="container2">
    <div></div>
    ...
    <div id="subject"></div>
    ...
    <div id="some_other"></div>
    ...
    <div id="subject"></div>
    ...
</div>
```

*And I know it's not a good practice to keep elements with same ID. But in this case I can't actually modify the HTML.*

So now in my logic I want to **hide** some element (which has the id '**subject**') inside **container** div element.
For the sake of the questions lets say I want to **hide the first div with id 'subject'** since there are multiple elements with id 'subject'.

The approach I tried is

```
containerElt = $("#container");
relevantDiv = $("#subject",containerElt);
relevantDiv.hide();
```

But it will hide all the elements inside container div, with id 'subject'. is there any smooth way to achieve my requirement.

it will be elegant if this can be done to the n'th element. But it's more than enough someone can show me how to do it for the first div with id 'subject'.

Comment: ID **should** be _unique_, **ALWAYS**

Comment: ID **should** be unique

Comment: `$('#subject').hide()` will hide the **first** element

Comment: `$('#container #subject').hide();`

Comment: _I can't actually modify the HTML._ **Answer:** If you want to select **third** element with id, use `$('[id="subject"]').eq(2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tf1qyr4m/

To get nth element use .eq(index) - index is zero based.
So :

```
relevantDiv = $('[id="subject"]').eq(0);
relevantDiv.hide();
```

To hide first one.

EDIT: Note that you must use $('[id="subject"]') in order to select more than first element.

https://api.jquery.com/eq/

Comment: "To get nth element use .eq(index) - index is zero based."  makes it general, with a link to eq selector and with JSFiddle example which actually hides 2nd element.

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
containerElt = $("#container");
// find the element with `subject` id(first matched element only)
containerElt.find('[id="subject"]:first').hide();
// or
containerElt.find('[id="subject"]:eq(0)').hide();
```

Comment: This will hide all the elements with that id, not what OP wants

Comment: Yes, this should hide that.